# SQLAlchemy relationship mapping error

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a program to log the process of my plants and the date of planting seeds. All the data is alailable via REST-Api but the last database migration buffles me. I want to save data about planting seeds (api.database.plantevent.py):

```
class Plantevent(BaseTable):
"""
The database model for a planting event when seeds are planted.
"""
    __tablename__ = 'plantevents'

    plantdate = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    seed_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('seeds.id'), nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Integer, nullable=False)  # number of planted seeds
    sprouted = Column(Integer)  # number of sprouted seeds
    soaked = Column(Boolean)  
    first_seedling = Column(Date)  # Date of the first seedling
    plants = relationship("Plant", backref='plantevent')
```

The "BaseTable" is an abstract table and contains only the id field.

If some seeds sprout I want to get all the plants of the "plantevent" through the "plants" relationship. Here is the model for a plant (api.database.plant.py):

```
class Plant(BaseTable):
"""
The database model for plants.
"""
    __tablename__ = 'plants'

    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    crop_yield = Column(Integer)
    plantevent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('plantevents.id'))
```

Everything works very good, except the "plant"-relationship in "Plantevent" and I can't figure out why. if I comment the "plant"-relationship, everything is OK.
Just for the completeness here is the schema of the produced sqlite-database:

```
CREATE TABLE plantevents (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  plantdate DATE NOT NULL, 
  seed_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  sprouted INTEGER, 
  soaked BOOLEAN, 
  first_seedling DATE, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(seed_id) REFERENCES seeds (id), 
  CHECK (soaked IN (0, 1))
);
CREATE TABLE plants (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  crop_yield INTEGER, 
  plantevent_id INTEGER, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(plantevent_id) REFERENCES plantevents (id)
);
```

The error I get, if I try to get a plantevent is the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Plantevent|plantevents, expression 'Plant' failed to locate a name ("name 'Plant' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'api.database.plantevent.Plantevent'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Has anyone an idea why I get this error? I compared it to other relationships in the db-model and I can't see any difference.

Edit:
Here is the model of the BaseTable (api.database.**init**.py):

```
class BaseTable(Base):
    """
    Abstract base table which provides the id field for each table
    """
    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Could you include the definition of `BaseTable` as well?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more, but I'd bet that nothing imports the module `api.database.plant` before trying to use `Plantevent` and thus the declarative class `Plant` is never created. What is not created can not be found in the metadata.